# Fitting a sigmoid function to incomplete, structured, data

Tags: curve-fitting

I have an incomplete data set that looks like this:
[image: Imgur]

and I believe that it will continue to form a sigmoid-like shape. How can fit a sigmoid curve to this data given my assumption about what the complete shape should look like?

I am trying to do this in R.

Comment: Have you seen this: http://kyrcha.info/tutorials/fitting-a-sigmoid-function-in-r/ ?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that sigmoid is optimal in this case, but I'd have to know about what you're trying to do to be sure.

Comment: I'm trying to model consumption of a limited resource. Consumption starts to peak around 300, but cannot keep increasing forever (because the resource is limited). I expect it stabilize at some point, but not decrease.